# Traer datos de multiples ID´s en laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tengo un formulario con mas de 70 campos (es gigantesco) y una tabla en la DB con esa misma cantidad de columnas, algunas de ellas están asociadas a un id de la tabla users.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen aparece un campo user_id y select_converter el cual hace referencia a un usuario de la tabla users ambos apuntan a la misma tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la vista en el campo convertidor asignado en vez de mostrar el numero 6 deberia mostrar el nombre del usuario de la tabla user con ID 6 de la columna select_converter, pero lo que hace es traerme el nombre del usuario con ID 4 de la columna user_id debido a la relación que tengo configurada en mi modelo.

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

pero esta misma relación no me funciona si necesito traer los datos del ID de la columna select_converter.

Quisiera saber en estos casos como hacer para obtener los atributos de ese ID por medio de eloquent y poderlos mostrar en la vista correctamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar dos relaciones.
Una es la que ya tienes definida:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Y la otra para converter (algo así):

```
public function converter()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'select_converter');

    }
```

Usarás una u otra en función de lo que quieras recuperar.
Para la primera:

`$elemento->user->nombre;`

Para la segunda:

`$elemento->converter->nombre;`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, funciono perfecto!!

Comment: Hola @DarwinGomez Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada. Sigue las instrucciones indicadas aquí: [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas)

Comment: Hola @pedroPrada, debido a que soy nuevo en la plataforma hasta que no tenga 15 puntos de reputación no me deja marcar la respuesta como aceptada para que se visualize pero en cuanto los tenga marcare la respuesta como aceptada, gracias por la ayuda que me ha brindado.